# Can I move tokens in Mipui?

Tags: tools, mipui

It seems like, when moving tokens in [Mipui](http://mipui.net/app) that I need to manually cut and paste the contents of cells.  Is this accurate? Is there a simpler/faster way to move tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use the token mode

When using the Token mode instead of Select it's possible to mouse over the existing token. In the top-left corner of the token there is a small white square. Move the mouse around until it turns into a white four-directional arrow. That is how you can drag the token around instead of cutting and pasting.

Comment: Note: This is unfortunately very hard to do in mobile mode :-( Until a future update addresses this, cut/paste is probably the best workaround for mobile.